# Is there a shortcut to type a symbol from a different keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 17.10, input-language

I use two keyboard layouts (English and Lithuanian) and have to switch between them constantly.
Windows had the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[symbol]</kbd> that would let me type an English keyboard symbol without fully switching the keyboard layout.

E.g.: 
I use the <kbd>1</kbd> key to print `ą`. If I want to type `!`, on windows I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to type `1`.

Is there a similar shortcut I could use in Ubuntu?

Comment: I believe you are looking to use the 'compose key' - some details can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey)

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Nope. The OP just needs to know how to make use of <AltGr>. Please see my answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Perhaps I'm mistaken, but isn't <AltGr> the compose key?

Comment: @CharlesGreen: By default there is no dedicated compose key. Many (most) keyboard layouts, e.g. the Lithuanian one, reserves <AltGr> (or <Right Alt>) for accessing third and fourth level key symbols. And when working like that, it's not called "compose key".

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Running the gnome-tweak tool, Ubuntu 17.10, under the "Keyboard & Mouse" section, the "Compose Key" is defined as <Right Alt> and can be changed to another key if desired.

Comment: @CharlesGreen: If it's defined as <Right Alt> for you, you must have picked <Right Alt> as the compose key previously. By default the compose key is disabled. (Otherwise there is a bug...) Let me guess: You use the _English US_ layout, which does not make use of 3:rd and 4:th level symbols. In that case it makes a lot of sense to use <Right Alt> as the compose key. For most other keyboard layouts, <Right Alt> is a pretty bad compose key choice.

Comment: Xkb has “groups” and if you have two layouts selected they should be two groups.  There are keys, and perhaps some layouts that uses those keys, for keys like “shift” for going to the next group.  Note that this is typically not the `AltGr` key; that is usually used to access the third level, and the third level is still within the same group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't type symbols from other layouts, but there is indeed an equivalent to access symbols which are actually part of the Lithuanian layout.

To type 1 with the Lithuanian keyboard layout:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

To better understand how the Lithuanian layout on Linux works: When Lithuanian is selected, click the layout indicator at the top right of the screen and select the *Show keyboard layout* option. That will show an image of the Lithuanian layout. Let's take the <kbd>1</kbd> key as an example:
[image]

That tells us:

1. <kbd>1</kbd> -> ą
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> -> Ą
3. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> -> 1
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> -> !

HTH

Comment: I actually never knew about the altGr key... It was there but I never knew what it was for as ctrl+alt essentially did the same thing for me. Thank you for the help!

Comment: “Well, you can't type symbols from other layouts, …”—You can.  There is `ISO_Group_Shift` which can be used to “shift” to the next layout.  That can be used to switch to the layout if you have set up the layouts with e.g. `setxkbmap "us,fr"` (assuming the layouts have the `ISO_Group_Shift` keys; I think the Japanese layouts have for one).

Comment: @Guildenstern: Maybe I'm missing something, but.. I didn't mean to say that you can't switch layout. The default shortcut in Ubuntu for doing so is <Super>+<Space>. The above question was about how to avoid that.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson the key that I mentioned functions as a shift key so it doesn’t function as `Super`+`Space`.  It doesn’t switch the layout, only “shifts” to the next layout while pressed.

Comment: @Guildenstern: Thanks for explaining; I've not stumbled upon that feature yet.